# error while connecting cassandra and spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have installed cassandra 2.1.11, spark 2.0.0.bin hadoop 2.7 and java version 1.8.0_101 on my ubuntu 14.04.
For the Spark Cassandra Connector, i have installed git

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
```

and build it

```
cd spark-cassandra-connector
git checkout v1.4.0
./sbt/sbt assembly
```

and placed the jar of scala on home directory

```
cp spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ~
```

and used the connector

```
bin/spark-shell --jars ~/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and in the scala promt

```
sc.stop
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I have created **test** keyspace and table **my_table** from cqlsh and to test the connection, i have run the following command

```
eval test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "my_table")
```

and got the error

```
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'CassandraConnector.class'.
Could not access type Logging in package org.apache.spark,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'CassandraConnector.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.
```

Is this due to the version mismatch of spark and cassandra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mismatch between Spark and Spark. You choose to use a 1.4.0 library with Spark 2.0.0.

Use the 2.0.0 release and also use Spark Packages.

https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

```
> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-M2-s_2.11
```

Comment: i am able to connect spark and cassandra. Now i would like to connect pyspark and cassandra, [pyspark_cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437584/connecting-integrating-cassandra-with-pyspark). How could and run this jar file?

Comment: replace "spark-shell" with "pyspark"